# How to install Maxima in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have used Maxima on Windows, and I'm now trying to install it in my laptop, which has Ubuntu 16.04 as its operative system. To do it I typed the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maxima
```

It worked, but then I type "maxima" in the terminal, Maxima opens *inside* the terminal (like Python) and not as a program with a GUI, as it happens in Windows. Is this the way it works in Ubuntu, or am I installing just a basic version of Maxima? How can I get a version like the one that runs on Windows, if this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

- [**wxmaxima**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/wxMaxima): GUI application for maxima

  Install running:

  ```
  sudo apt install wxmaxima
  ```
- **xmaxima**: X-interface

  Install running:

  ```
  sudo apt install xmaxima
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! wxmaxima is what I was looking for. :)